# ASP.net Contact us page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

This is a pretty simple question as i am new to asp.net i am trying to develop a contact us page and i am getting the following error.

"Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_nameBox' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

The following is my code so far for that page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ContactUs.aspx.cs" Inherits="Craigavon_Aquatics.ContactUs" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<h2>
    Contact Us</h2>
<p>
    Please fill in the form below to contact us.</p>

<p>
    &nbsp;</p>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name: (Required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<asp:TextBox ID="nameBox" runat="server" Width="278px"></asp:TextBox>                
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email: (Required)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either place a wrapper `<form runat="Server">` in your master page around the contentplaceholder, or on that page inside the `<asp:Content>` tag add a `<form runat="server">` that surrounds your current content.

**Site1.Master**

```
<form runat="server">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ...></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

-OR-

**ContactUs.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ...>
  <form runat="server">
    ...existing HTML code...
  </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the control with the ID of 'ContentPlaceHolder1_nameBox' and place in between the .aspx's form /form tags to get rid of the error.  ASP .Net Server controls have to be within the Form tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need  `<form runat="server">` // your code, controls .. `</form>` tag to surround your code. this is probably missing from your master page

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check and make sure that you have a form declared on the master page. Since I can't see that, then I would have to assume that there isn't one if that error is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to wrap the body inside  at your MasterPage.
But you could also override it like this.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) 
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All controls in your master page should be inside a `<form>...</form>` tag, including your content placeholders.

This has nothing to do with a "contact page". This is fundamental to ASP.NET pages in general.